# Fragment overlapping appbar

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-appbarlayout

I have a possible overlapping fragment containing listView. The layout looks fine in the preview window, however, when I run it on device or Emulator the appbar goes missing.

Main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".GuiseMainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentProps"></fragment>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:gravity="top|center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/propCategoryListView"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Class

```
public class GuiseMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =     getSupportFragmentManager();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    FragmentProps fragmentProps = new FragmentProps();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content,fragmentProps);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}}
```

Fragment Class

```
public class FragmentProps extends Fragment{

private View PropsFragmentView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    PropsFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_props, container, false);
    String[] propsCategories ={"Recently used", "Popular", "New", "Personalities", "Moustaches / Beard", "Caps/ Hats", "Glasses", "Banners"};

    ListAdapter propsCategoryListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, propsCategories);
    ListView propCategoryListView = (ListView) PropsFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.propCategoryListView);

    propCategoryListView.setAdapter(propsCategoryListAdapter);
    propCategoryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String categoryPicked = "You Picked: " + String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), categoryPicked, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    return PropsFragmentView;
}}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSEd7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, MainActivity Extends AppCompatActivity then add these lines in onCreate method:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.applogo);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Thanks guys.